# To change the value in App Config File after the Installation of a windows Application Form in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, app-config, setup-project

I want to to install my application in different sites where each site access different outlook account.

below is the line in my app config file:

```
 ! <add key="OutlookAccount" value="abc@xyz.com" />
 string RoomConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings ["OutlookAccount"]; 
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = 
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)session.CreateRe‌​cipient(RoomConfig);
```

So, how can i change the emil id in app config in a setup file or after installation?

Comment: which tool you are using for installation. actually you can edit your app config during installation depending on your target environment.

Comment: I have done my application in C# windows Application Form. Its to display all the calendar appointments of a shared folder. so i need to change the outlook email Id for each meeting room.

Comment: what's the problem editing manually?

Comment: @haiza ,how did you install the application in different sites ,how did you deploy your windows forms exe..

Comment: @HameedSyed I have just created a setup program. not yet deployed.

Comment: string RoomConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings ["OutlookAccount"];
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)session.CreateRecipient(RoomConfig); This is how i use the value in App config

Comment: Usually the tool used for deploying .net especially c# programs is install shield.So while running the installation wizard you can provide a textbox to configure your app.config from user end.

Comment: @HameedSyed how to add a text box like that?

Comment: Install shield you have to know.For time being I would suggest you to go to the setup path and change the app.config according to your need and run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do this after the install then just create a configuration program or an extra configuration dialog in your app to specify the mail settings. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but this seems like a fairly easy solution.